# Dropbox vs Google Drive vs other for free static cloud hosting

Tags: cloud-hosting

I need to host a static website, single page deal, and instead of paying for hosting I thought I might use a cloud service, however an issue I can see of this is bandwidth allowance. Does anyone know which allows more bandwidth per link, Dropbox, Google Drive or another service?

Comment: We don't accept questions here that compare and contrast web hosting.   We have a single question that gives general advice about web hosting, but that is all.

Comment: I see, i was not aware of this policy. I will delete this as soon as I have access to a computer rather than a phone.